# Float Pointer to Hexadecimal

Tags: python, floating-point, hex

The code I use to convert `hexadecimals > float pointers`:

```
from ctypes import *

def convert(s):
    i = int(s, 16)                   # convert from hex to a Python int
    cp = pointer(c_int(i))           # make this into a c integer
    fp = cast(cp, POINTER(c_float))  # cast the int pointer to a float pointer
    return fp.contents.value         # dereference the pointer, get the float

print convert("41973333")    # returns 1.88999996185302734375E1

print convert("41995C29")    # returns 1.91700000762939453125E1

print convert("470FC614")    # returns 3.6806078125E4
```

But I am not sure how I could reverse this effect, so to say.

I'm trying to go from `float pointer > hexadecimal`, instead of `hexadecimal > float pointer`.

Comment: You don't convert hexadecimal to float pointers. You use type punning to convert an hexadecimal representation of a float value to that float value. The Pythonic way is the `struct` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the same thing, but backwards:

1. Cast the float to an int
2. Convert the int to hex

The code:

```
def float_to_hex(x):
    fp = pointer(c_float(x))
    ip = cast(fp, POINTER(c_int))
    x = ip.contents.value
    return '{:02X}'.format(x)
```

Output:

```
>>> float_to_hex(1.88999996185302734375E1)
'41973333'
>>> float_to_hex(1.91700000762939453125E1)
'41995C29'
>>> float_to_hex(3.6806078125E4)
'470FC614'
```

Comment: TypeError: must be real number, not str

Comment: Sorry, `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    FloToHex('1.88999996185302734375E1')
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 2, in FloToHex
    fp = pointer(c_float(x))
TypeError: must be real number, not str` when I reproduce your exact code and example.

Comment: @CandyGum ...well, why are you passing in a string instead of a float?

Comment: @CandyGum This is probably because of the Exponential term in the float

Comment: @ankur09011 It was because I passed it as a string, but problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `struct` to convert hex to float

```
import struct

struct.unpack('!f', '41995C29'.decode('hex'))[0]
```

will give:

```
19.170000076293945
```

Comment: Yeah, if I wanted to convert hex to float, but that is not the case.